# Unwanted modification of not intricated lists

Tags: python, list

here is the code:

```
with open('units.txt', 'r') as f:
   print(f.readlines())
   e = [elt.split(" ")[0] for elt in f.readlines()]
   print(f.readlines())
```

and here is the result:

```
['INPUT 0 2 #ffffff # # #\n', 'OUTPUT 2 0 #ffffff # # #\n', 'NOT 1 1 #ff0000 # # #\n', 'AND 2 1 #8888ee # # #\n', 'NAND 2 1 #ff00ff INPUT_OUTPUT_AND_NOT_ #3,0,_#0,0,_0,1,_#2,0,_# 0_3_2_1_']       
[]
```

what am i missing ?

Comment: Try commenting out the `print(f.readlines())`. The file pointer is most likely not getting reset after the print so the second read just exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already called `readlines()` on an open file. You need to reset the file pointer using `file.seek(0)` before calling it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't keep calling `readlines` on the file, because the first consumes the entire file then the rest doesn't read anything. Store it to a variable:

```py
with open('units.txt', 'r') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
   print(lines)
   e = [elt.split(" ")[0] for elt in lines]
   print(lines)
```

Alternatively, call `f.seek(0)` between calls to reset the file pointer, but storing to a variable is far cleaner.

Comment: thank you ! A bit weird that 'reading' empties it ...

Comment: Every file has a file pointer that determines where to start the next read, and reads advance the file pointer so you can incrementally read from the file. This goes against what you want, so `f.seek(0)` will reset the file pointer to the start if you need multiple reads.